# Apply Q expire Policy for all Vhosts in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I need to apply Q expire Policy for all Vhosts in RabbitMQ,Is there any way we can apply a policy for all Vhosts from commandline.

Comment: Can you give some information about "Q expire policy"?

Comment: Queue should get deleted within 1 min,, https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html ,,, rabbitmqctl set_policy expiry ".*" '{"expires":60000}' --apply-to queues

Comment: Please update the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no.

you could write a script like this:

```
for i in `rabbitmqctl list_vhosts`; do
rabbitmqctl -p $i  set_policy expiry "" '{""expires":60000"}' --apply-to queues
done;
```

I think you have to skip the first two values